# in assembly x86 ... runTime Error when ECX hold odd number (loop)

Tags: assembly, x86

this program for reverse array (swapping) in x86 assmebly, but it have `runTime Error` when the number of element is odd

```
.data
arr dword 9 dup (1) ; if elements=10 no problem ..!!

.code

main proc
    mov ecx, (lengthof arr )
    mov esi,0
    mov edi,(lengthof arr-1) * type arr
lp:
    mov eax , arr[esi]
    xchg eax , arr[edi]
    mov arr[esi] ,eax
    add esi, type arr
    sub edi, type arr
    dec ecx
    loop lp

    retn
main endp

end main
```

Comment: downvoted because this is really easy to debug with a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`loop` already decrements `ecx`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/LOOP:LOOPcc.html), so you're having the same issue as [Issue With Using dec to Create a Delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39060303/issue-with-using-dec-to-create-a-delay).

```
dec   ecx
loop  lp
```

is the same as

```
dec   ecx
dec   ecx
jnz   lp
```

or

```
sub   ecx, 2
jnz   lp
```

If the counter starts odd, it goes from 1 to -1, so the check-for-zero is never true.  If you used `jg` to loop while it was positive, it would work.  So you run off the end of the arrays that you're looping over with `esi` and `edi`.

**You would have easily seen this if you'd watched the value of `ecx` change as you single-stepped through your loop in a debugger**.  (see the bottom of the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for tips on using gdb for asm).

---

code-review:

Don't use `xchg` with memory unless you need the atomic read-modify-write feature (implicit `lock` prefix), because it's *much* slower than just using a separate load/store.

You also clobber the caller's value of `esi` and `edi`, which are call-preserved in most ABIs.

---

#### What to do instead:

Don't use `ecx` as a loop counter, since you're already using esi and edi as indices.  Just `cmp / ja` them to stop looping when they pass each other.  The `loop` instruction is a bad choice most of the time, because it's slow and often you already have something in another register that works as a loop counter.

---

e.g.

```
main proc
    push   esi
    mov    esi, OFFSET arr      ;  not just arr, since this isn't NASM
    lea    ecx, [esi + (lengthof arr-1) * type arr]     ; ecx = pointer to last element
swaploop:
    mov    eax, [esi]           ; need to use different register sizes if type arr isn't 4 bytes
    mov    edx, [ecx]

    mov    [esi], edx           ; store to opposite locations
    mov    [ecx], eax

    add    esi, type arr
    sub    ecx, type arr
    cmp    esi, ecx
    jb     swaploop            ; while(low < high)   // (unsigned compare)

    pop    esi
    ret
```

Note that the `mov eax, [esi]` / `add esi, 4` [could be a `lodsd` instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/LODS:LODSB:LODSW:LODSD:LODSQ.html), but then you'd need a -4 displacement for the store address, and it's probably slower.